# Interpretation of Total Effects, Direct Effects and Indirect Effects (Pearl, 2012)

Tags: causality, mediation

Pearl (2012) introduced a Mediation Formula to assess mediation effects in non-linear models. I would like to ask how to interpret the results if the Total Effect (TE) is negative, but both the Direct Effect (DE) and the Indirect Effect (IE) are positive.

Using the same notations as in Sections 3.4 (The binary case) and 3.5 (Numerical example) of his paper, the data are as follows:

> g_1,1 = 1.00
>
> g_1,0 = 0.60
>
> g_0,1 = 0.67
>
> g_0,0 = 0.73
>
> h_0 = 0.62
>
> h_1 = 0.17

Using Equation 4 (TE), Equation 6 (DE) and Equation 8 (IE), I obtained the following:

> TE = -0.025
>
> DE = 0.160
>
> IE = 0.027

I am not sure how to interpret these results, especially since both the DE and the IE are positive while the TE is negative.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Added g_1,1 = 1.00 because I realised that I had left that piece of information out.